# Trying to bind syncfusion json data to realtime database in Firebase

Tags: c#, json, firebase, rest, syncfusion

I’m trying to use the Scheduler tool in Syncfusion (blazor).I’m Binding to remote data in a realtime firebase.

If I import data in the correct format as below (ID=0) I can see it in the scheduler & all works well. If I import another as ID= 2 manually it will continue on working well.

[image: database]

The random ID -MajbecDwqY04jsocuS2 assigned by the scheduler interface messes up the order & stops it working. How would I ensure the id numbers increment by 1 to work correctly.

```
<div class="col-lg-12 control-section">
    <div class="schedule-wrapper">
        <SfSchedule TValue="ScheduleData.AppointmentData" Width="100%" Height="650px" @bind-SelectedDate="@CurrentDate" Readonly="false">
            <ScheduleEventSettings TValue="ScheduleData.AppointmentData">
                <SfDataManager Url="https://firebasekey.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/scheduler.json" Adaptor="@Syncfusion.Blazor.Adaptors.WebApiAdaptor"></SfDataManager>
            </ScheduleEventSettings>
        </SfSchedule>
    </div>
</div>


 public class AppointmentData
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Subject { get; set; }
            public string Location { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
            public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
            public Nullable<bool> IsAllDay { get; set; }
            public string CategoryColor { get; set; }
            public string RecurrenceRule { get; set; }
            public Nullable<int> RecurrenceID { get; set; }
            public Nullable<int> FollowingID { get; set; }
            public string RecurrenceException { get; set; }
            public string StartTimezone { get; set; }
            public string EndTimezone { get; set; }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can order by id value and get the last element added and increment it to use it as next key.

Example code for a cloud function that does that:

```js
const lastItemSnap = await firebase
  .database()
  .ref("scheduler")
  .orderByChild("id")
  .limitToLast(1)
  .once("value");

const lastKey = lastItemSnap.key;

//Increment key and use it for the next element
const newKey = parseInt(lastKey) + 1;

await firebase.database().ref(`scheduler/${newKey}`).set({ test: "your data" });
```

Make sure to order by `id` because the keys would be ordered as strings.